# What happens when you evolve a pokemon while it's in a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I noticed that while my pokemon is defending a gym, it can evolve (or looks like it could since the button is not faded out). You can tell it is in the gym because the team insignia is on the CP circle.

[image: Dat Caterpie]

Has anyone tried this? Does my Caterpie become a Metapod at the gym or does it stop me from evolving?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: I was deciding whether I wanted to test this, or save my candies. Went to catch some pokemon in the mean time, but by the time I tried to test it, my caterpie was already kicked out of the gym.

Comment: @BrettBender it shows on the top of the Q, no?

Comment: Yes, I just realized and can't remove my own comment ... :(